# Extend tuples in one list using tuples from another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. Both lists will have the same sets of rows. I would like to add list2 columns to list1 to create one list.

```
list1 = [('gi1','1','2'),
    ('gi1','1','2'),
    ('gi1','1','2')]

list2 = [('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'),
    ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'),
    ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')]
```

I would like to merge these into a list that looks like this:

```
[('gi1','1','2','a','b','c','d','e','f','g'),
('gi1','1','2','a','b','c','d','e','f','g'),
('gi1','1','2','a','b','c','d','e','f','g')]
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html Take a look at the second function. You can iterate through and use that function per element, right?

Comment: Found my answer.

new = []
extend = self.tel.verboseIf()
for f,b in itertools.izip(creation,extend):
 row = (f,b)
 new.append(row)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the help of [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
>>> list1=[('gi1','1','2'),
           ('gi1','1','2'),
           ('gi1','1','2')]
>>> list2=[('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'),
           ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'),
           ('a','b','c','d','e','f','g')]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> [tuple(chain(x, y)) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
[('gi1', '1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('gi1', '1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('gi1', '1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')]
```

Comment: or `list(map(tuple,map(chain,li1,li2)))` if you're feeling spicy.

Comment: I used: list(map(tuple,map(chain,li1,li2)))
it worked perfectly. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

If you know that both lists have the same length:

```
[list1[i] + list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it. Use `Zip()`

```
>>> [e1+e2 for e1,e2 in zip(list1,list2)]
[('gi1', '1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('gi1', '1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('gi1', '1', '2', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')]
```